# Depending on the generation order of my tkinter frames only one or two of my animation.FuncAnimation works

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, matplotlib-animation

I do have a problem with my matplotlib animations in my tkinter windows.

currently only one or two of the animated plots get animated. One of them works all the time and the other two arr dependent on the order in the following code.

```
for F in (x_page, y_page, ani1_page, ani2_page, ani3_page):
        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

 self.draw_frame(ani1_page)
```

in the current order `ani1_page` and `ani3_page` get animated, if i put `ani1_page` on the last position only that page gets animated.
if I switch positions of `ani2_page` and `ani3_page`, `ani2_page` gets animated and `ani3_page` is not animated.

Comment: How are you storing your `FuncAnimation` objects?  They are a bit unusual in that you have to keep a reference to the object to keep the animation going, even though you aren't directly doing anything with the object.  An attribute of the page displaying the plot would be a reasonable choice.  I suspect you're using a single global variable, so only the last created animation still has a reference to it.

Comment: `ani_1_graph = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(ani_1_f, ani_1_plot, interval=1000)
ani_2_graph = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(ani_2_f, ani_2_plot, interval=1000)
ani_3_graph = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(ani_3_, ani_3_plot, interval=1000)`

That is probably what you were speaking of, I think there should be no error here

Comment: Are the `ani_X_graph` variables global?  Local variables would mean that the animation ends as soon as the function exits.

Comment: Yes they are global, it really seems like one of those functions just gets completely ignored by the program

Comment: Would you alternatively know a way of refreshing a plot on a tkinter buttonpress? Just executing the function used in the animation doesn't do anything to my plot